# How to add new object ArrayList of Array to inside another ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

So, I have this code , where basically I want to put a String Array to inside of an ListArray, then put that ListArray to inside of another ListArray.  While I know how to put a new object of Array , I can't seem to find a way to put a new ListArray object to another ListArray

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class HelloWorld
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

    ArrayList<List<String[]>> menues = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String[]> items = new ArrayList<String[]>();

    String price = "$12";

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            String name = "Item Code-" + String.valueOf(i) + String.valueOf(j);
            items.add( new String[]{name, price} );
        }
      menues.add(items); // This line is the cause
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            System.out.println(menues.get(i).get(j)[0]);
        }
    }

  }
}
```

There Result I expect is

```
Item Code-00
Item Code-01
Item Code-02
Item Code-03
Item Code-04
Item Code-10
Item Code-11
Item Code-12
Item Code-13
Item Code-14
Item Code-20
Item Code-21
Item Code-22
Item Code-23
Item Code-24
```

The Result THAT I GOT (basically just repeating the same thing)

```
Item Code-00
Item Code-01
Item Code-02
Item Code-03
Item Code-04
Item Code-00
Item Code-01
Item Code-02
Item Code-03
Item Code-04
Item Code-00
Item Code-01
Item Code-02
Item Code-03
Item Code-04
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the *creation* of `items` inside the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    ArrayList<String[]> items = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        String name = "Item Code-" + String.valueOf(i) + String.valueOf(j);
        items.add( new String[]{name, price} );
    }
    menues.add(items); // This line is the cause
}
```

Otherwise you add the same `items` all over again which results in the outer list containing the *same* list 3 times.